# Use xmlstarlet to convert XML containing repeated and missing fields to tab delimited

Tags: xml-parsing, xmlstarlet, csv

I have a large complex XML file containing a pattern like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <record>
    <field1>field1</field1>
    <field2>field2</field2>
    <field2>field2</field2>
    <field3>field3</field3>
    <field4>field4</field4>
    <field4>field4</field4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field1>field1</field1>
    <field1>field1</field1>
    <field3>field3</field3>
    <field4>field4</field4>
    <field4>field4</field4>
  </record>
</records>
```

I would like to use xmlstarlet to convert it to tab delimited with repeated fields subdelimited with a semicolon, e.g.

```
field1\tfield2;field2\tfield3\tfield4;field4
field1;field1\t\tfield3\t\field4;field4
```

I can do what I need by collapsing repeated fields with a string processing routine before feeding the file to xmlstarlet but that feels hacky. Is there an elegant way to do it all in xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked. Nevertheless...

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) version 1.6.1 to extract and sort field names
to determine field order, and then produce tab-separated values:

```shell
xmlstarlet sel \
-N set="http://exslt.org/sets" -N str="http://exslt.org/strings" \
-T -t \
--var fldsep="'$(printf "\t")'" \
--var subsep="';'" \
--var allfld \
  -m '*/record/*' \
    -v 'name()' --nl \
  -b \
-b \
--var uniqfld='set:distinct(str:split(normalize-space($allfld)))' \
-m '*/record' \
  --var rec='.' \
  -m '$uniqfld' \
    --sort 'A:T:-' '.' \
    -v 'substring($fldsep,1,position()!=1)' \
    -m '$rec/*[local-name() = current()]' \
      -v 'substring($subsep,1,position()!=1)' \
      -v '.' \
    -b \
  -b \
--nl < file.xml
```

**EDIT**: `--sort` moved from `$allfld` to `-m $uniqfld`.

where:

- all field names in input are collected in the `$allfld` variable
- the [exslt](/questions/tagged/exslt) functions [`set:distinct`](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html)
  and [`str:split`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html)
  are used to create a nodeset of unique field names from `$allfld`
- the `$uniqfld` nodeset determines field output order
- repeated fields are output in document order here but `-m '$rec/*[…]'`
  accepts a `--sort` clause
- the `substring` expression emits a separator when `position() != 1`

Given the following input, which is different from OP's,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <record>
    <field2>r1-f2A</field2>
    <field2>r1-f2B</field2>
    <field3>r1-f3</field3>
    <field4>r1-f4A</field4>
    <field4>r1-f4B</field4>
    <field6>r1-f6</field6>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field1>r2-f1A</field1>
    <field1>r2-f1B</field1>
    <field3/>
    <field4>r2-f4A</field4>
    <field4>r2-f4B</field4>
    <field5>r2-f5</field5>
    <field5>r2-f5</field5>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field6>r3-f6</field6>
    <field4>r3-f4</field4>
    <field2>r3-f2B</field2>
    <field2>r3-f2A</field2>
  </record>
</records>
```

output becomes:

```
    r1-f2A;r1-f2B   r1-f3   r1-f4A;r1-f4B       r1-f6
r2-f1A;r2-f1B           r2-f4A;r2-f4B   r2-f5;r2-f5 
    r3-f2B;r3-f2A       r3-f4       r3-f6
```

or, piped through `sed -n l` to show non-printables,

```
\tr1-f2A;r1-f2B\tr1-f3\tr1-f4A;r1-f4B\t\tr1-f6$
r2-f1A;r2-f1B\t\t\tr2-f4A;r2-f4B\tr2-f5;r2-f5\t$
\tr3-f2B;r3-f2A\t\tr3-f4\t\tr3-f6$
```

---

Using a custom field output order things can be reduced to:

```shell
xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
--var fldsep="'$(printf "\t")'" \
--var subsep="';'" \
-m '*/record' \
  --var rec='.' \
  -m 'str:split("field6 field4 field2 field1 field3 field5")' \
    -v 'substring($fldsep,1,position()!=1)' \
    -m '$rec/*[local-name() = current()]' \
      -v 'substring($subsep,1,position()!=1)' \
      -v '.' \
    -b \
  -b \
--nl < file.xml
```

again emitting repeated fields in document order in absence of `--sort`.

Note that using an EXSLT function in a `--var` clause requires the
corresponding namespace to be declared explicitly with `-N` to avoid
a runtime error (why?).

To list the generated XSLT 1.0 / EXSLT code add `-C` before the `-t` option.

To make one-liners of the formatted `xmlstarlet` commands above -
stripping line continuation chars and leading whitespace - pipe
them through this `sed` command:

```
sed -e ':1' -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;/\\$/!b;$b;N;s/\\\n[[:blank:]]*//;b1'
```

---

To list elements in the input file `xmlstarlet`'s `el` command can be
useful, `-u` for unique:

```shell
xmlstarlet el -u file.xml
```

Output:

```
records
records/record
records/record/field1
records/record/field2
records/record/field3
records/record/field4
records/record/field5
records/record/field6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)  command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/records/record" -m "*[starts-with(local-name(),field)]" -i "position()=1" -v "." --else -i "local-name() = local-name(preceding-sibling::*[1])" -v "concat(';',.)" --else -v "concat('\t',.)" -b -b -b -n input.xml
```

In pseudo-code, it represents something like this

- For-each `/records/record`
- For-each element-name that starts with `field`
- If it's the first element, output the item
- Else
- If check if the current element name equals the preceding one
- Then output `;Item`
- Else output `\tItem`
- `b` does mean "break" out of loop or if clause
- `n` outputs a newline

Its output is

```
field1\tfield2;field2\tfield3\tfield4;field4
field1;field1\tfield3\tfield4;field4
```

---

The above code differentiates on the base of element names. If you want to differentiate based on element values instead, use the following command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/records/record" -m "*[starts-with(local-name(),field)]" -i "position()=1" -v "." --else -i ". = preceding-sibling::*[1]" -v "concat(';',.)" --else -v "concat('\t',.)" -b -b -b -n a.xml
```

With your example XML the output is the same (because field names and field values are identical).

Comment: For clarity, the field names vary considerably and require attribute filters to select so the -m switches to descend into repeated fields that might not exist were tripping me up. So I'll need to play a bit with some  of the ideas in your solution

Comment: The other issue I'm encountering with your solution is that it doesn't include a null value if a field is missing. For example, the second record lacks field2 -- but it's essential for delimited output to contain the same fields in the same columns. If there were a way to simply back up a level after an -m sequence, this would be a piece of cake.

Comment: You can "back-up" a level with the `-b` option. But I'm yet to find a solution for this...

Comment: I found a solution that works in my specific case. The XML I'm working with is complex, but each record contains a unique identifier. By extracting all the identifiers into an array which can be looped through, I can build filters that allow me to build match expressions from root that allow me to iterate and create subdelimiters. Performance has been better than expected -- several records per second -- so it's clean and acceptable. Not quite what I hoped for, but still not bad.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a workable solution. Good luck and have a nice day.

Comment: I appreciate you taking a stab at it. Even though I wasn't able to use your solution, there's some good stuff in it and it was clearly written, so it may help someone else with another problem